# What does public worker mean?

Tags: meaning

What does the word "public worker" mean? I have searched through Internet and there was no definition for the word public worker. However, i found a definition for the word "public works" which according to the dictionary it means projects set up by the government for public use such as roads, bridges, schools and etc. Based on what "public works" mean, i have thought public worker could mean someone who is involved with public works. I am not sure if i am right or not, so i just wanted to ask here.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A "public worker" is someone who works for the government. It would include teachers at public schools (i.e. government-run schools), policemen, bureaucrats, etc.

"Public works" means government-run construction projects. So a public worker might well be involved in public works, but they also could be doing many other things.

I should clarify that this is American usage. I don't know if it's different in other English-speaking countries. I think it's the sort of word that might be.

Comment: I think _civil servant_ is a similar word, but with different usage.

Comment: Yes, I think "civil servant" means pretty much the same as "public worker". If there's a distinction, I'm not sure what it is. Most civil servants I've meet are neither civil nor act like servants, so I think it's a pretty misleading term.

Comment: I'd add that often, private companies are hired to build public works like bridges or givernment buildings. The company's employees don't work for the government, so many people involved in building a public works are not public employees.

Comment: @Karen Quite true.

Comment: @Jay The two can differ in some things. "Civil servants" is the proper translation of the term that Czech laws use for people who are "protected" -- the police, doctors, FD etc. If you commit a crime against these people, you face stronger penalties and sentences than if you commit the same crime against other people. This doesn't apply to all public workers, but can, on the other hand, apply to people not paid directly from public funds.

Comment: @yo' I don't think they have the same distinction in English (at least, American English).  Certainly, civil servants include accountants, bureaucrats, and others who work on the taxpayers' payroll, here.

Comment: @Joe In the US, "civil servant" certainly doesn't mean "every public employee" - in addition to excluding the military, elected officials and political appointees are not civil servants. Civil servants are career government employees who are hired, promoted, assigned, and disciplined through a bureaucracy, with protection from political interference. High-level officials who are politically appointed might be called "public servants" in their official bios, but wouldn't be considered civil servants.

Comment: I certainly would consider an elected official a civil servant, and political appointees.  Military I suppose you are probably right (though I think they're also not public servants).

Comment: @Joe That's not how I hear the term used, although this may be because I'm from DC and there might be more need for the distinction. Appointed officials might be called civil servants if they rose through the ranks (e.g. generals); elected officials never are. Civil servants are permanent career staff who aren't easily subject to political interference; jobs can't be handed out as gifts to supporters, and they can't be fired easily (personnel actions are merit-based). I'm not sure if this is a distinction mostly found among people who work in/with government, but it's a major distinction.

Comment: @cpast I think we're into distinctions between technical use of a term and general use. Like "force" and "work" have very specific technical meanings to a physicist that do not apply to normal, day-to-day usage. The U.S. federal government has specific categories of employees who are supposed to be outside the political process, i.e. when a new president is elected he is expected to replace the policy-making people but not the career bureaucrats. So by the technical, legal definitions, the Secretary of Commerce  is not a "civil servant". But if you asked the average person on the street, ...

Comment: ... I think they'd say that he is. Then, I suppose, you could get into a debate about whether this is different definitions in different contexts, or if the people who say he IS a civil servant are "wrong".

Comment: @Jay: What do you mean by " but they also could be doing many other things" ?

Thanks

Comment: @GforOevOerD I mean "things other than construction work". That is, "public works" are government-run construction projects. So someone working on such a project could be a "public worker". But teachers and fireman and policeman are also "public workers", and they don't normally do construction work.